# Can't access YouTrack, unless using Firefox

Tags: firefox, port, amazon-ec2

**Problem**

I cannot access JetBrains YouTrack using Chrome or Internet Explorer, but I can access it using Firefox.

**Background and troubleshooting that has already been performed**

- It is running on an Amazon EC2 instance.
- I have hosted it on port 82.
- I have TeamCity hosted on port 81 and that is working perfectly in any browser, from anywhere
- I have opened up those ports in the Windows Firewall, as well as in the EC2 security group manager.
- The same problem occurs whether I access the site:

  - using the public IP address from my laptop
  - using the public IP address while logged into the EC2 instance
  - using localhost on the EC2 instance.
- The problem does not occur, i.e. everything works fine, if I try either of the three steps above using Firefox.
- I'm pretty sure it *was* working in Chrome, but now I'm doubting myself.
- Probably irrelevant: I recently had to stop and start the EC2 instance due to an underlying hardware error, so that it could be migrated to new infrastructure.
- I've checked the network settings in IE and Firefox on my local machine, and they're both set up with default settings.

**Question**

What's with that?

Comment: AFAIK IE/Chrome will try to automatically configure proxy settings in a way that might not be the same as FF (the former will use Windows' network stack more than FF will). In the past I've found Fiddler to be a good tool for discovering "surprise" proxy settings. Tools => Fiddler Options => Gateway => Show Current Gateway Info.

Comment: I did that. The output was:
WPAD: Not detected

Comment: While Fiddler is running can you try accessing it with FF/IE and watching what happens? Also in IE are you trying `http://whatever:82` i.e. including the protocol (https if necessary). From past experience IE doesn't try to guess protocols if you give it a non-standard port.

Comment: Thanks, ta.speot.is. Using fiddler to look at the request made the problem apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a configuration problem that is redirecting to /login with a malformed ip address, so the 302 redirect request was failing.

I must have just been logged in on firefox, so no redirection was taking place.